# Two players alternate coloring $3\times 3$ squares in $n\times m$ rectangle

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

So I'm writing a game and I'm supposed to implement optimal play from the computer's part, however I cannot find any strategies.

The game is played on $n\times m$ board. Each turn a player selects one uncolored square then colors it and all other squares around it (a total of $9$), which means that those colored squares cannot be selected again.

The player who is unable to select a square loses (so the one with the last step wins).

The only thing I could come up with is that if $n,m$ are both odd, the starting player can win by starting in the middle and then mirroring all the steps.

Comment: the 9 squares must be free? or i can select any square free with a neighboring cell not free?

Comment: Can't you use minimax and use exhaustive search? If the board is not big enough, say 20*20, it's quite easy computation wise.

Comment: (As it can be seen in the example), only the center (selected) squares must be free, the neighbouring ones can overlap with already colored ones or can be outside of the board (if center square is in the margin of the board)

Comment: f.rodrigues: It is definitely doable, but it's not a strategy which would lead to victory/ advantage. I'm looking for a (partial) solution which make plays more optimal.

Comment: Of course it would, in fact it would find the optional move since doing exhaustive search on all possible outcomes of the board and assign a value to each 'node' on the tree, say +1 for win and -1 for loss. Going up the tree would have some nodes with bigger and bigger win/lose ratios, until you are the root of the tree and have the optional path.

Comment: @f.rodrigues Aren't there too many possibilities in the case of a $20\times 20$-board to apply exhaustive search?

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't lead to victory/optimal play, the emphasis was on the part that it cannot be considered as a strategy, which could be used by human players too, like in other similar games.

Comment: @Peter I don't think so, would have to test it thou. But since the game removes 9 blocks in the best case (the bulk of the game) until there are only single blocks to remove (fast search space).

get_student, I thought you were trying to make an AI to play against a human player. If there's a optional playstyle it's best for AI, even thou it's hard for humans to mimics. If you want to make the AI weaker, you can select randomly from the best k moves depending on the AI difficulty.

Comment: FWIW, the non-attacking kings problem analysis can provide you with some bounds: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KingsProblem.html

Comment: This doesn't relate directly, but you may be interested in the this mirroring solution for odd and even order Sudoku games (impartial) which seems to extend to partizan forms, at least for the even-order Sudoku boards: http://jdh.hamkins.org/infinite-sudoku-and-the-sudoku-game/